# div class in php echo

Tags: php, css

I would like to put a background on my guestbook messages and the font color should be white. How can I change the echo:

```
 <?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
        include ('dbconnection.php');
        include 'checklogin.php';
        include 'head_nav.html';
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="descripion" content="Die offizielle Seite von BestFoto">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Foto, Fotografie, BestFoto, Business, Architektur, Fashion, Natur">
        <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright 2017 by Sharam Etemadi">
        <meta name="author" content="Sharam Etemadi">
        <title>BestFoto &ndash; Kontakt</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div class="container">
                        <div class="main-content-container">
                <div class="content-header-container">
                    <header class="content-header">
                        <h1>Kontakt</h1>
                    </header>
                </div><!-- content-header -->
                <div class="content-container">
                    <section class="content">
                    <p>
                        Hier könnt ihr Verbesserungsvorschläge oder sonstiges einreichen.
                    </p> 
                    </section>
                </div><!-- content-container -->
            </div><!-- main-content-container -->
            
            
                        
           <form action="" method="post">
            <p>Betreff:</p>
            <input type="text" name="betreff" placeholder="Betreff?"><br>
            <p>Nachricht:</p>
            <textarea name="nachricht" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht!"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Absenden!"><br>
        </form>
        <?php
        array_walk ( $_POST,    'cleanmsg' );
        array_walk ( $_GET,     'cleanmsg' );
        array_walk ( $_REQUEST, 'cleanmsg' );
 
        function cleanmsg(&$value, $key)
        {
            // keine HTML-Tags erlaubt, außer p und br
            $value = strip_tags($value, '<p><br /><b><strong>');
 
            // HTML-Tags maskieren
            $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES);
 
            // Leerzeichen am Anfang und Ende beseitigen
            $value = trim($value);
        }
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
                $betreff = $_POST['betreff'];
                $nachricht = $_POST['nachricht'];
                $userid = $_SESSION['user'];                
                $StrSQL = "INSERT INTO kontakt (userid_fk,betreff,nachricht,datum)
                VALUES (?,?,?,NOW())";                                                
                $absenden = $db->prepare($StrSQL);                       
                $absenden->bind_param('iss', $userid, $betreff, $nachricht);
                $absenden->execute();
            endif;
            $StrSQL2 = "SELECT users.benutzername as bn,
            kontakt.betreff, kontakt.nachricht, kontakt.datum
            FROM users RIGHT JOIN kontakt
            ON users.userid = kontakt.userid_fk ORDER BY datum DESC";             
            $abfrage = $db->query($StrSQL2);                   
            echo  'Es wurden '.$abfrage->num_rows.' Nachrichten gefunden!<br>';
            ?>
            
<?php while ($ausgabe = $abfrage->fetch_object()) { ?>
    <div class="test">
        <b>user:</b><?=!is_null($ausgabe->bn) ? htmlspecialchars($ausgabe->bn) : 'Guest'?>
        <br>
        <b>Date:</b><?=$ausgabe->date?>
        <br>
        <b>subject:</b><?=htmlspecialchars($ausgabe->subject)?>
        <br>
        <b>message:</b>
        <br>
        <?=htmlspecialchars($ausgabe->message)?>
        <br>
        <hr>
    </div>
<? } ?>
<?php
// rest of the PHP code

        $result_total = mysqli_query($db,'SELECT COUNT(*) as `total` FROM kontakt');
        $row_total = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_total);
        $gesamte_anzahl = $row_total['total'];

        $ergebnisse_pro_seite = 10;
        $gesamt_seiten = ceil($gesamte_anzahl/$ergebnisse_pro_seite);

        if (empty($_GET['seite_nr'])) {
            $seite = 1;
            } else {
                $seite = $_GET['seite_nr'];
        if ($seite > $gesamt_seiten) {
            $seite = 1;
    }
}

        $limit = ($seite*$ergebnisse_pro_seite)-$ergebnisse_pro_seite;

        $result = mysqli_query($db,'SELECT `nachricht` FROM `kontakt` LIMIT '.$limit.', '.$ergebnisse_pro_seite);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Ausgabe deiner Daten
} 

for ($i=1; $i<=$gesamt_seiten; ++$i) {
    if ($seite == $i) {
        echo '<a href="kontakt.php?seite_nr='.$i.'" style="font-weight: bold;">'.$i.'</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="kontakt.php?seite_nr='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
}


         include 'footer.html';  
        
    ?>  
        
        
        </div><!-- container -->

    </body>
</html>
```

now with a div class, so I can write this in my css?

Edit: I have inserted the whole code for you, maybe who can overlook which error is present? After I have inserted the accepted answer, I get a white screen and nothing is displayed anymore. Unfortunately I also don't get an error

Comment: I don't see any div or css in this question? If you want to add a div, just add a div?

Comment: `echo '<div>  your current content </div>';`? You're just echoing HTML so just add what you need in the string.

Comment: Yes, and you can add styles to the test class in your CSS

Comment: Yes. But you have a typo. You need to add a `'` before the first `<br>` or you will get parse errors.

Comment: Yes. But instead of keep posting it here and asking if it looks correct, just try it and see if the output looks correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and ditch those echo garbage. Make the HTML first class citizen and then mix PHP into it:

```
<?php
// php code
?>
<?php while ($ausgabe = $abfrage->fetch_object()) { ?>
    <div class="test">
        <b>user:</b><?=!is_null($ausgabe->bn) ? htmlspecialchars($ausgabe->bn) : 'Guest'?>
        <br>
        <b>Date:</b><?=$ausgabe->date?>
        <br>
        <b>subject:</b><?=htmlspecialchars($ausgabe->subject)?>
        <br>
        <b>message:</b>
        <br>
        <?=htmlspecialchars($ausgabe->message)?>
        <br>
        <hr>
    </div>
<? } ?>
<?php
// rest of the PHP code
```

Comment: @Sha Updated the code. Just open the PHP code block with `<?php` and close with `?>`. Open the block with `<?=` if you want the result of the PHP code in that block to be automatically echoed. Remember to use `htmlspecialchars` on echoed content to deal with XSS attacks.